# Where to store expected output of a test?

Tags: java, xml, testing, properties

Writing a test I expect the tested method to return certain outputs. Usually I'm checking that for a given database operation I get a certain output. My practice has usually been that of writing an array as a quick map/properties file in the test itself.
This solution is quick, and is not vulnerable to run-time changes of an external file to load the expected results from.

A solution is to place the data in a java source file, so I bloat less the test and still get a compile-time checked test. How about this?

Or is [loading the exepected results as resources](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-test-resource.html) a better approach? A .properties file is not good enough since I can have only one value per key. Is [commons-config](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Using_PropertiesConfiguration) the way to go?

I'd prefer a simple solution where I name the properties per key, so for each entry I might have a `doc-length` and `numFound` property value (sounds like the elements of an xml node)?

How do you go about this?

Comment: Interesting question! All the testing we do here is with static data. In that case having the expected results defined in your test code works fine. Would like to know this!

Comment: +1| comment : A key can have one value but the value can represent several values separated by comas

Answer (score 3):

You must remember about maintaining such tests. After writing several web services tests with Spring-WS test support I must admit that storing requests (test setup) and expected responses in external XML files wasn't such a good idea. Each request-response pair had the same name prefix as test case so everything was automated and very clean. But still refactoring and diagnosing test failures becomes painful. After a while I realized that embedding XML in test case as String, although ugly, is much easier to maintain.

In your case, I assume you invoke some database query and you get a list of maps in response. What about writing some nice DSL to make assertions on these structures? Actually, [FEST-Assert](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Fluent+Assertions+Module) is quite good for that.

Let's say you test the following query (I know it's an oversimplification):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rs = db.query("SELECT id, name FROM Users");
```

then you can simply write:

```
assertThat(rs).hasSize(1);
assertThat(rs.get(0))
  .hasSize(2)
  .includes(
    entry("id", 7),
    entry("name", "John")
  )
);
```

Of course it can and should be further simplified to fit your needs better. Isn't it easier to have a full test scenario on one screen rather than jump from one file to another?

Or maybe you should try [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org) (looks like you are no longer doing unit testing, so acceptance testing framework should be fine), where tests are stored in wiki-like documents, including tables?

Comment: I've found the exact opposite - I've found it much easier to look at the data for a test when it's *not* in a string, which is either going to incur concatenation cruft or be all on one line, and may require escaping too. Additionally, when you use separate files it's easier to get other tools to check that those files are valid - you don't end up chasing invalid XML strings.

Comment: I'm with Jon on this one. In addition, test data embedded in the source code requires a recompile whenever you want to change the data.

Comment: That's the crux of the q! I had the data in a csv and then coming back to the test after a long while (apparently I was using -DskipTests) it took me ages to figure out that the test was indeed right but that the problem was that I had accidenently modified the test..after that I placed all the csv in the code and that jar ALWAYS works, but the class is now bloated, and with the editor line wrapping it becomes too slow to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using resources for expected results (and also setup data) works well and is pretty common.

XML may well be a useful format for you - being hierarchical can certainly help (one element per test method). It depends on the exact situation, but it's definitely an option. Alternatively, JSON may be easier for you. What are you comfortable with, in terms of serialization APIs?

Comment: "What are you comfortable with, in terms of serialization APIs?" none? I've XML and CSV parsed before (JSON only JS), but they are sth I look up every time (~rare)..How about you post some example code for the sake of reference?

Comment: @simpatico: It's hard to do that without knowing what's required, and frankly I don't want to get back into Java XML APIs unless I have to :( Definitely look at something like JDom instead of the built-in XML APIs.

Comment: there you go, xml parsing is not a straightforward solution!

Comment: @simpatico: It's not something I want to do for fun in my free time, and without bothering to bring up an IDE and download JDom. It shouldn't be too bad, just not a pastime...

Answer (score 2):

Given that you mention you are usually testing that a certain DB operation returns expected output, you may want to take a look at using [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html#assertdata):

```
 // Load expected data from an XML dataset
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("expectedDataSet.xml"));
    ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("TABLE_NAME");

    // Assert actual database table match expected table
    Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
```

DBUnit handles comparing the state of a table after some operation has completed and asserting that the data in the table matches an expected `DataSet`. The most common format for the `DataSet` that you compare the actual table state with is probably using an `XmlDataSet`, where the expected data is loaded from an XML file, but there are other subclasses as well.

If you are already doing testing like this, then it sounds like you may have written most of the same logic already - but DBUnit may give you additional features you haven't implemented on your own yet for free.

Comment: Uh - prove what? That this library might be useful to someone? Or how to use it? The link to the DBUnit Getting Started page, in my answer, is intended to do that. I cannot hope give better samples on how to use DBUnit than what appears in the project's documentation.

Comment: @matt - and if I'm not testing a db (like now)? I'm testing a servlet (which BTW has an index/db behind) and checking that for given queries I get expected results?

Comment: Typically in a test of a component like a servlet, you would [mock out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the layers used to access the DB/data so that your servlet test is not dependent on the DB code, so you can test these things independently - in other words, you shouldn't be testing DB logic in your servlet unit test. DB layer unit tests tend to have lots of data that you need to set up and verify, which makes externalizing the data with a tool like DBUnit or others a good idea. Unit tests of servlets or other web layer stuff typically have far less test data involved.

Comment: @matt - i'm testing a servlet which is a blackbox I've no access to the DB behind it. How about that?

Comment: then in that case what you are doing is not called "unit-testing". As to your earlier question about "and if I'm not testing a db?"; a testing tool like `DBUnit` is meant for assisting in DB unit testing, so clearly it's only really of value in database-related tests. Finally, I don't really get the antagonistic tone in a lot of your comments here towards people offering suggestions and answers for a question in which you asked for help.

Comment: @ matt - Yeah, sorry didn't mean to be rude. It's just that so many times I feel ppl work around answering the problem, by saying things 'u shouldn't do that in the first place', 'this is always a smell of bad design' etc.. which is at most good for a comment. I agree, I'll remove the unit-testing tag.